# Detect if agent (person) is within a circle

Tags: anylogic

Similar to the Exposure to Radiation example model, I'd like to update a person's exposure level depending on whether they are in a circle or not. I'm using a SD flow to increment a totalExposure stock. The CurrentExposureLevel flow is determined by a function `exposureLevel(person.getX(), person.getY())` and returns an int. The function body is:

```
int l = 0;
if(myCircle.contains(x, y)){
    l = 5;
}
return l;
```

The person follows a path which passes through the circle, but not for the entire length of the path. The issue I'm experiencing is that the flow never runs, and therefore the stock doesn't increment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to constantly check if the agent is inside the circle. Use a cyclic event that calls your function code. Or adjust it to return `boolean` (true if inside, false if not) and adjust your value accordingly.

Obviously ensure your event checks often enough :)

Note: If you replace your oval presentation with a shape from the material-handling library, they have actual code boxes "on enter" and "on exit". You could use those instead of a cyclic event, if applicable.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue by removing the process modeling elements altogether and then associating the agent with the path network on startup with `setNetwork(main.walkNetwork);`